# OkHttp POST body not received

Tags: php, android, okhttp

Am using okhttp to send and receive data to and from the server not working as expected or am I doing something wrong.

My Android Client Side, bear in mind I have already instantiated the client okHttp object and my containing class already implements the `.enqueue` asynchronous methods.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("usr", "alex");
final MediaType JSON
        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(config.SERVER_GET_RECEIPTS)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
client.newCall(request).enqueue(this);
```

The response from my server side is a string I put in place if the `$_POST` variable is empty. and it returns this string.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    echo "Properly Parsed" . $_POST['usr'];
}else{
    echo "Not Properly Parsed";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the `RequestBody.create(JSON, json);` you should send `obj.toString()` as the json parameter, so at the end it would be something like this `RequestBody.create(JSON, obj.toString());`